# Does anybody know of any way to create a market ambience sound?

Tags: film, sound-design, sound-effects

Working on a project with a scene in a middle eastern marketplace. I've attempted to record a conversations between me and 2 other people standing far away from the mic, and then layering, but it doesn't sound quite right. Has anybody managed to achieve a similar sound using this technique? Any other techniques I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps grab a recorder and make a trip to a few outdoor markets and layer those. Can't beat actually going out and getting the recordings! I know it won't be much like the markets in the middle east but it might give you a start. You could also go through sound websites and see if there are elements that you could use.

Comment: Definitely look to mask language with vehicular traffic, handling foley, or other sound sources that might obscure the language used in the background. 

Answer (score 0):

Definitely recording the real thing or using a recording of the real thing or something that's convincing enough. If it has to sound realistic, it could be difficult to make it sound convincing even with a recording from for example a western marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment and have fun with it. What comes to my mind are three specific layers. Go record a crowd layer. This could be say, a talkative crowd waiting for a seminar to begin or after a choir concert is over. Then record yourself + friends letting out the occasional shout of something "middle-eastern" sounding, as if you are all peddling your wares. Then, find some "middle eastern" music appropriate to the locale, and place that in the distance to add a more festive feel and to reinforce the setting.

Comment: You may also want to record a Foley track of baskets/trays/goods being spilled and tossed around occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with the other posts in saying that recording an actual market place could be the way to go. Not sure where you're from but if you're near a big city there might be some ethnic areas where you could get some realistic crowd walla type stuff even though you're not in the Middle East!

Answer (score -2):

Try Audioease Speakerphone.

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: Select any outdoor preset.